# NoSuchModuleError: sqlalchemy-access

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, spyder, sqlalchemy-access

I have a script that queries and updates an access table. I've used it successfully on my computer, but after installing anaconda and spyder on a different computer (same versions as the original installation on the original computer) it doesn't work on the new computer.
To clarify: I installed the package using
`pip install sqlalchemy-access`
on the anaconda prompt, and when running
`pip list|findstr access`
I get
`sqlalchemy-access                  1.1.3`. However, when I run the script in spyder I get the `NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:access.pyodbc` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but after trying multiple times, I checked again (`pip list|findstr access`) and found that the installation of sqlalchemy-access, which I managed to find before in the anaconda prompt, has disappeared. I installed it again (for the third or fourth time) and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have several different python versions on your computer?

Maybe installing the package with

`pip3 install sqlalchemy-access`

Could fix this.

Comment: I Tried it now. It did not make a difference.

Comment: Okay, then maybe check, if the sqlalchemy-access package is within the right directory or at least in a directory, where python / anaconda looks for packages. If not done yet, a re-installation of the package might help as well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).